# Domain of definition of $\log \log z$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the region where the complex function $\log \log z$ is defined.

I don't understand the question. Should I literally just find where the function is defined, or where the map $z \mapsto \log \log z$ is single-valued?

Comment: You need to go out on a limb here...

Comment: Do you know what a branch point is?

Comment: Does your "$\log$" denote a specific branch of the complex logarithm?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$log logz$ can be defined everywhere in the complex plane except at $z=0$ and $z=1$.
I am assuming the question asks for the points at which the function can exist.

Comment: Why $z=1$? (You could take a branch of $\log z$ for which $\log 1 \neq 0$.)